# Why is FileSystemWatcher events not firing

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher, sql-server-2019

I am trying to determine when my SQL Server log file changes.

I wrote a simple program:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var logDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log";

            using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(logDirectory);

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                                   | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                                   | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                                   | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                   | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                   | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                   | NotifyFilters.Security
                                   | NotifyFilters.Size;

            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            //watcher.Created += OnCreated;
            //watcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
            //watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
            watcher.Error += OnError;

            watcher.Filter = "ERRORLOG.*";
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            while (true)
            {
                // Empty Loop
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in watcher.");
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ErrorLog has changed.");
    }
}
```

I get no errors in the debug window and no output in the console. While it is running, I log in with SSMS. I check the directory and both the `ERRORLOG` file size and modified date have changed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not nessesarily related but either put a sleep in the while loop or replace the while loop with a console.readline. doing one of those two options will make your progam stop using 100% of a cpu core.

Comment: Isn't the active error log file name in SQL server _just_ called ERRORLOG? ERRORLOG.* is used for _archived_ log files. Your filter won't match the active log.

Comment: @Nick Thanks, fixed. I still get nothing however.